# Why uses React old values for state?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, speech-recognition

I'm currently working on an App where the user can work through some algorithms. Somethings like:
Question --> Answer1, Answer2, Answer3. Based on the answer, the next question changes.

I'd like to use speech recognition, so i implemented [react-native-voice](https://github.com/react-native-voice/voice). Theres a microphone image turning green, when the recognizing start. If the input is correct, the app shows buttons with all possible answers. The selected answer is green and the next step appears. It's working quite fine until the user jumps back.
If I'm going back to a free text answer, it works fine until a new input starts. I have a state with `clickedButtons`  where are the selected answers are stored. I watched the `clickedButtons` array with a `useEffect`. The button for the answer jumped back is removed until a new speech input starts. I don't add any button or something if i start the speech input. But react uses the old state, with more buttons.

Heres the code for the VoiceControl.js:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { Dimensions, Image, Text, TouchableHighlight } from "react-native";

import { decode } from "html-entities";
import Tooltip from "react-native-walkthrough-tooltip";

import Voice from "@react-native-voice/voice";
import AnswerOptions from "./AnswerOptions";

export default function VoiceControl(props) {
  //DEFINITION VARIABLEN
  const step = props.step; //Variable mit dem zu verarbeitenden Schritt
  const stepsDone = props.stepsDone; //Array mit bereits erledigten Schritten
  const clickedButtons = props.clickedButtons; //Array, welches die IDs der bereits geklickten Buttons beinhaltet
  const currentAlgorithmJson = props.currentAlgorithmJson; //Aktuellen Algorithmus von den Props auslesen

  const [micVisibility, toggleMicVisibility] = useState(true); //Variable, ob das Mikrofon Bild angezeigt wird oder nicht
  const [micImage, setMic] = useState(
    require("../../assets/Images/Record.png")
  ); //Bild mit Mikrofon, wird grün sobald Spracherkennung aktiv ist
  const [tooltipContent, setTooltipContent] = useState(""); //Inhalt für den Tooltip, welcher im Fehlerfall angezeigt wird
  const [tooltipVisibility, toggleTooltipVisibility] = useState(false); //Variable für die Sichtbarkeit des Tooltips
  const [speechValue, setSpeechValue] = useState(""); //Variable zum Speichern des Textes bei freier Texteingabe

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("----------");
    console.log(step["Question"]);
    console.log(clickedButtons);
    console.log("----------\r\n");
  }, [clickedButtons])

  //DEFINITION FUNKTIONEN
  function onButtonClicked(id, buttonText) {
    if (step["Action"][buttonText] === "Done") {
      navigation.navigate("Übersicht"); //Ist der Algorithmus beendet, wird zur Übersicht navigiert, um nächsten Algorithmus zu starten
    } else if (step["Action"][buttonText] === "Reanimation") {
      navigation.navigate("Algorithmus", { algorithm: "Reanimation" });
    } else if (
      clickedButtons.filter((oldId) => oldId.includes(step["Question"]))
        .length > 0
    ) {
      //Falls auf einen bereits erledigten Schritt zurückgegangen wird...
      props.updateButtons(
        clickedButtons.splice(0, stepsDone.indexOf(step)).concat(id)
      ); //Gewählte Buttons werden bis zum Index des Schrittes beibehalten und der neue Button wird ergänzt
      props.updateSteps(
        stepsDone
          .splice(0, stepsDone.indexOf(step) + 1)
          .concat(currentAlgorithmJson[step["Action"][buttonText]])
      ); //Schritte werden bis zum Index des aktuellen Steps beibehalten und der nächste Schritt ergänzt
    } else {
      props.updateButtons(clickedButtons.concat(id)); //ID zum Array hinzufüge, um angeklickte Buttons zu markieren
      props.updateSteps(
        stepsDone.concat(currentAlgorithmJson[step["Action"][buttonText]])
      ); //Nächsten Schritt definieren und zum "Schritte Array hinzufügen"
    }
  } //Funktion, wenn beim Ablauf eines Algorithmuses ein Button gedrückt wird

  function onTextInputClicked() {
    // props.updateButtons(clickedButtons.splice(0, stepsDone.indexOf(step)));
    let buttons = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < stepsDone.indexOf(step); index++) {
      buttons.push(clickedButtons[index]);
    }
    props.updateButtons(buttons);
    props.updateSteps(stepsDone.splice(0, stepsDone.indexOf(step) + 1)); //Wenn Text geklickt wird, springt der Algorithmus so zurück, dass die Eingabe verändert werden kann (Button aus clickedButtons löschen und alle darauffolgenden Steps entfernen)

    destroyVoice();
    Voice.onSpeechStart = () => {
      console.log(clickedButtons);
    }
    Voice.onSpeechEnd = () => {
      setMic(require("../../assets/Images/Record.png")); //Endet die Spracheingabe, wird das Mikrofon wieder schwarz
    };

    Voice.onSpeechResults = async (e) => {
      processSpeechInput(e["value"]); //Input verarbeiten, wenn die Ergebnisse des Inputs verfügbar sind
      destroyVoice(); //Alle Voice Objekte zerstören, weil sonst auch vorherige Fragen beeinflusst werden
    };

    Voice.onSpeechError = async () => {
      setMic(require("../../assets/Images/RecordFailed.png")); //Mikrofon Bild aktualisieren (rotes Mikrofon / Spracherkennung fehlgeschlagen)

      setTooltipContent(
        "Ich konnte dich leider nicht verstehen. Versuche es erneut!"
      ); //Tooltip Text erzeugen mit Fehlermeldung
      toggleTooltipVisibility(true); //Tooltip anzeigen
      destroyVoice(); //Alle Voice Objekte zerstören, weil sonst auch vorherige Fragen beeinflusst werden
    };
    toggleMicVisibility(true);
  } //Funktion, wenn im Algorithmus zu einem TextInput zurück geganen werden soll

  function processSpeechInput(values) {
    const lower = [];
    values.forEach((value) => {
      if (!lower.includes(value.toLowerCase())) {
        lower.push(value.toLowerCase());
      }
    }); //Array mit verstandenen Antworten im LowerCase

    const intersection = Object.keys(step["Action"]).filter((button) =>
      lower.includes(button.toLowerCase())
    );
    //Spracherkennung versteht "ja", Antwort ist aber "Ja" ==> Um Antworten zu vergleichen wird der LowerCase verwendet

    //Wenn die Schnittmenge zwischen verstandenen Antworten und möglichen Antworten größer 0 ist, entspricht die Antwort eine möglichen Antwort...
    if (intersection.length > 0) {
      onButtonClicked(
        step["Question"] + " : " + intersection[0],
        intersection[0]
      ); //Nächsten Schritt laden und verarbeiten
      toggleMicVisibility(false); //Mikrofon ausblenden
    }
    //Wenn die Antwort ein TextInput ist, wird jede Eingabe akzeptiert
    else if (Object.keys(step["Action"]).includes("TextInput")) {
      onButtonClicked(step["Question"] + " : TextInput", "TextInput"); //Nächsten Schritt laden und verarbeiten
      setSpeechValue(values[0]); //Verstandene Antwort in Variable speichern, um diese so an nächste Komponente übergeben zu können
      toggleMicVisibility(false); //Mikrofon ausblenden
    }
    //Wenn die verstandene Antwort keiner verfügbaren Antwortmöglichkeit entspricht und es auch keine freien Texteingabe ist...
    else {
      let possibleAnswers = "";
      for (const buttonText in step["Action"]) {
        possibleAnswers += "\r\n" + decode("&#10142;") + " " + buttonText;
      }
      setTooltipContent("Mögliche Antworten sind:" + possibleAnswers); //Tooltip Text erzeugen mit allen Antwortmöglichkeiten
      toggleTooltipVisibility(true); //Tooltip anzeigen
    }
  }

  async function startVoice() {
    let recognizing = false;
    await Voice.isRecognizing().then((active) => (recognizing = active)); //Auslesen, ob gerade eine Spracherkennung aktiv ist

    //Falls keine Spracherkennung aktiv ist...
    if (!recognizing) {
      setMic(require("../../assets/Images/RecordActive.png")); //Mikrofon Bild aktualisieren (Grünes Mikrofon / Spracherkennung aktiv)
      await Voice.start("de-DE"); //Spracherkennung starten
    }
  }

  async function destroyVoice() {
    Voice.removeAllListeners();
    await Voice.destroy();
  } //Alle Voice Instanzen Objekte zerstören

  useEffect(() => {
    Voice.onSpeechEnd = () => {
      setMic(require("../../assets/Images/Record.png")); //Endet die Spracheingabe, wird das Mikrofon wieder schwarz
    };

    Voice.onSpeechResults = async (e) => {
      processSpeechInput(e["value"]); //Input verarbeiten, wenn die Ergebnisse des Inputs verfügbar sind
      destroyVoice(); //Alle Voice Objekte zerstören, weil sonst auch vorherige Fragen beeinflusst werden
    };

    Voice.onSpeechError = async () => {
      setMic(require("../../assets/Images/RecordFailed.png")); //Mikrofon Bild aktualisieren (rotes Mikrofon / Spracherkennung fehlgeschlagen)

      setTooltipContent(
        "Ich konnte dich leider nicht verstehen. Versuche es erneut!"
      ); //Tooltip Text erzeugen mit Fehlermeldung
      toggleTooltipVisibility(true); //Tooltip anzeigen
      destroyVoice(); //Alle Voice Objekte zerstören, weil sonst auch vorherige Fragen beeinflusst werden
    };

    const timeout = setTimeout(async () => {
      startVoice();
    }, 2000); //Timeout Funktion, so dass die Spracherkennung nach 2 Sekunden gestartet wird

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      destroyVoice();
    };
  }, []); //Verarbeitungsfuntktionen für die Spracherkennung initialisieren

  if (micVisibility) {
    return (
      <Tooltip
        isVisible={tooltipVisibility}
        content={<Text>{tooltipContent}</Text>}
        placement="center"
        onClose={() => toggleTooltipVisibility(false)}
      >
        <TouchableHighlight
          key={step["Question"] + " : Image"}
          style={{
            width: Dimensions.get("window").width - 20,
            height: 50,
            marginTop: 5,
          }}
          onPress={async () => startVoice()}
        >
          <Image
            style={{ width: 50, height: 50, alignSelf: "center" }}
            source={micImage}
          />
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </Tooltip>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <AnswerOptions
        step={step}
        clickedButtons={props.clickedButtons}
        onButtonClicked={(id, buttonText) => onButtonClicked(id, buttonText)}
        onTextInputClicked={() => onTextInputClicked()}
        textinputValue={speechValue}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Can somebody tell me, why react uses here the old states?
Because of the same or another weird reason it destroys the `stepsDone` state, which stores the steps already done. If i restart the recognition it only contains the following steps after the one i jumped back too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As workaround I found the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
    Voice.onSpeechEnd = () => {
      setMic(require("../../assets/Images/Record.png")); //Endet die Spracheingabe, wird das Mikrofon wieder schwarz
    };

    Voice.onSpeechResults = async (e) => {
      processSpeechInput(e["value"]); //Input verarbeiten, wenn die Ergebnisse des Inputs verfügbar sind
      destroyVoice(); //Alle Voice Objekte zerstören, weil sonst auch vorherige Fragen beeinflusst werden
    };

    Voice.onSpeechError = async () => {
      setMic(require("../../assets/Images/RecordFailed.png")); //Mikrofon Bild aktualisieren (rotes Mikrofon / Spracherkennung fehlgeschlagen)

      setTooltipContent(
        "Ich konnte dich leider nicht verstehen. Versuche es erneut!"
      ); //Tooltip Text erzeugen mit Fehlermeldung
      toggleTooltipVisibility(true); //Tooltip anzeigen
      destroyVoice(); //Alle Voice Objekte zerstören, weil sonst auch vorherige Fragen beeinflusst werden
    };
  }, [clickedButtons]);
```

So i'm reinitializing the events on every render the buttons changes. It works, but i still don't know why react used the old values...